# Is there a way to change how an element with a subclass is affected by the :hover event?

Tags: css, web

I have a class ".form-option-card", and a succeeding class ".form-option-selected". For context, any unselected option will just have form-option-card, and the selected option will have ~selected. I'd like the properties of hovering the selected card to be different, if possible?

I've tried adding 2 interpretations of the hover events, as follows:

```css
.form-option-card {
    padding: 16px 24px;
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 0.5px solid #d1d1d122;
    margin: 0px 0px 12px;
    max-width: 570px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 64px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    transition: transform 0.1s, border-color 0.5s, background-color 0.2s, box-shadow 0.1s;
}

.form-option-card:hover {
    transform: scale(1.01);
    background-color: #ffffff05;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #ffffff19;
}

.form-option-card:hover .form-option-selected {
    background-color: #6454f305;
}
```

but, obviously, this isn't working otherwise I wouldn't be here. Any ideas?

Comment: Please show HTML. If both classes are on same element, than do `.form-option-card.form-option-selected:hover`

Comment: If `.form-option-selected` is a child of `.form-option-card`, your proposed code should work. If it's a sibling, look into [CSS combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators). If the element is adjacent to the hovered element, you can use the `~` combinator. If it's not adjacent, get creative, like so: `.form-option-card:hover + .adjacent-element + .form-option-selected` (depends on the markup, of course)

Comment: Does the card when selected have both classes? If so use .form-option-card .form-option-selected:hover

Comment: All the above comment guess work shows why a [mcve] is required of all questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is the rule in your code:

```
.form-option-card:hover .form-option-selected
```

Written like this, the rule applies to an element with the class `.form-option-selected` which is a **descendant element** of an element with the class `.form-option-card` which is in the hover state. And I'm guessing this doesn't match anything in your HTML, which is why it's not working.

What you probably meant was this:

```
.form-option-card.form-option-selected:hover
```

This rule applies to an element with **both** the classes `form-option-card` and `form-option-selected`, and which is in the hover state.

However, you probably don't need to include both class selectors in your rule. Just make a rule for `form-option-selected:hover` and put it **after** the rule for `form-option-card:hover`, as demonstrated in this snippet.

```css
.form-option-card {
    padding: 16px 24px;
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 0.5px solid #d1d1d122;
    margin: 0px 0px 12px;
    max-width: 570px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 64px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    transition: transform 0.1s, border-color 0.5s, background-color 0.2s, box-shadow 0.1s;
}

.form-option-card:hover {
    transform: scale(1.01);
    background-color: cyan;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px red;
}

.form-option-selected {
    background-color: lime;
}

.form-option-selected:hover {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-option-card">A</div>
<div class="form-option-card form-option-selected">B</div>
```